# Salesforce Liveagent - Can Client share files with Operator?

Tags: liveagent

I have a LiveAgent custom chat page and want a file sending feature: I wants that a client can share files with operator during a salesforce LiveAgent session.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be done similar to standard Live Agent File Transfer feature. You have to add `<liveAgent:clientChatFileTransfer />` inside `</liveAgent:clientchat>` element.

To enable `Transfer Files During a Chat` feature please follow this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=live_agent_transfer_files.htm&type=0) or [Live Agent for Support Agents](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/live_agent_support_agents.pdf).

> Update

First Operator has to initiate the File Transfer Request from Service Console as below.

[image]

Then client can see a link saying "*Upload or drag your file here.*" and a Cancel button. By clicking this button client can upload the files.

[image]

You can change the text of the link and cancel button by using these attributes `fileTransferUploadLabel`, `fileTransferCancelFileLabel` available for `liveAgent:clientChatFileTransfer`. Check this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_liveAgent_clientChatFileTransfer.htm) for more details.

Also, you can add CSS to change the style of the link and cancel button as per your need.

Comment: Hi guys , i found it : i have the same problem of [this unsolved question](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000MJy8IAG) but i don't know how i can solve it

Comment: Are you not able to see the "File Transfer Request" icon in Service console?

Comment: Yes , i cannot see the icon in Service console ; i can see only the  Attach Files Icon .

Comment: Did you enable "live Agent File transfer" in settings?

Comment: Do you mean 'Agent File Transfer Enabled' flag on Live Agent Configurations page? yes , i've the same situation of that unsolved case

Comment: Hi Saroj ; in my Custom ChatWindow Page i add the tag liveAgent:clientChatFileTransfer but in my console operator i can't see the attachment loaded. Here is the link of the image that explain my expected result and my actual problem. (http://imgur.com/a/YZuj7)